# iOS UNUserNotificationCenter keeps receiving notifications after turning notifications off

Tags: ios, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter

I'm seeing some unexpected behaviour in my app and was hoping someone could help to explain it.

I have an app that receives notifications, and when the user opens the app it uses the `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications` API to get all the notifications still in the user's Notification Center.

Notifications as sent fairly regularly by our service through APNS.

However, if the user subsequently turns off notifications for my app at the system level (switching off in the Settings app), it appears that Notification Center is *still* receiving notifications. Even though no notifications appear in the Notification Center on the device, calling `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getDeliveredNotifications` always returns new notifications that the user would have received normally if they had notifications switched on.

I'm really confused by this behaviour. I would expect APNS to stop sending notifications to a user who has turned them off for an app. Even for a user who has had notifications turned off for a month, `UNUserNotificationCenter` is still returning new delivered notifications.

Is this perhaps something to do with iOS 12's Deliver Quietly feature? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It was working in iOS 12, but not in iOS 13. It seems from iOS 13 it started working as a documented:

> If none of your app’s notifications ***are visible*** in Notification Center, the array is empty

Unfortunately I can not find this change in release notes ...

So once notifications are turned off by the user notifications are no longer visible in Notification Center and will not be returned in `getDeliveredNotifications`

Comment: Thanks, I had forgotten I even asked this question. Good to hear iOS 13 works as expected. I'm still surprised it worked the way it did in iOS 12.